# TimerBlox LTC6992 PWM variable clock generator at 2.3MHz... out of tolerance or used incorrectly?

Tags: clock, square, signal-generator

The TimerBlox LTC6992 (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf) is a PWM chip specified to have a master output frequency maximum of 1MHz, and provides a set of pins (MOD, SET, and DIV) to control the output square wave. I built a circuit that fixes the duty cycle near 50%, and allows for the divider and master frequency to be adjusted by potentiometers. What's baffling me is I'm getting over 2.3MHz out of this chip. I'm not sure whether I've misunderstood the technical limitations of the LTC6992, or if my chip is damaged and somehow out of tolerance.

For some context, this circuit will be used to generate a variable clock speed on a Z80 microcomputer, and there is an engraved label plate involved that I would like to rely on being engraved accurately.

My circuit consists of three main parts, each of which I will explain.

**The MOD Signal**
This is a simple voltage divider producing around 0.5V. While the chip states the MOD signal can be effected by the SET signal, it is not significant in my circuit and a static 0.5V holds the duty cycle very near 50% at all times.

**The SET Signal**
The 6992 holds this pin at 1V and looks for current sink via a resistor R<sub>SET</sub> between 50K and 800K (see top of page 4). A parallel 4M resistor and 1M variable resistor generate 0-800K resistance, which is in series with a 24K resistor producing the range 24K to 824K, just over the maximum range specified on either end.

**The DIV Signal**
The DIV signal drives a set of discrete values detected by an internal ADC with preset ranges. From 0v to VCC/2, the available denominators are 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>6</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>10</sup>, 2<sup>12</sup>, and 2<sup>14</sup>. If VCC/2 is exceeded, the scale reverses and the polarity of the duty cycle is inverted. My circuit uses a small variable resistor to prevent the larger potentiometer from ever passing the VCC/2 boundary. It is a simple variable voltage divider between 0V and 2.5V.

Here is the relevant portion of my circuit as I planned it in a simulator. Please note that some components are represented by a pin header showing they would plug into the board rather than being soldered to it.
[image: Snapshot of LTC6992 circuit diagram showing how the MOD, SET, and DIV pins are used]

And here is a photograph of a breadboard prototype of that circuit:
[image: A breadboard with an LTC6992 chip adapted to a DIP-8 and the various circuits for controlling it]

Running with both dials turned left (no division and highest base frequency) I see over 2.3MHz, 230% the specified maximum for this chip.
[image: Oscilloscope display showing a 2.326MHz square wave]

Running with both dials turned right (highest division and lowest base frequency) I see a reasonable 3.68Hz, which is very close to the specified 3.81Hz minimum.
[image: Oscilloscope display showing a 3.676Hz square wave]

Context notes:

- All VCC is at 5V
- The 6992 is a surface mount component, and I've soldered it to a 2.54mm adapter. The board has been cleaned aggressively with alcohol and an antistat brush.
- The 6992 is further nested in a socket because the pins weren't long enough for a breadboard

Have any other details you want me to add? I'll add them to this list.

**TL;DR** Why is this LTC6992 running faster than 1MHz, and am I able to prevent this behavior?

**Adjustments made per the posted solution:**
The R<sub>SET</sub> value must be clamped to the range 50K to 800K. I formerly assumed it would clamp internally based on the wording of the data sheet. To achieve this, I've replaced the 24K resistor with a 100K variable resistor, tunable to exactly 50K. I've also replaced the 4M balance resistance with 2M plus a 2M variable resistor. This resistor can be tuned to produce a total resulting resistance of 50K (set by first pot) to 800K. This circuit is confirmed to produce a near-perfect 3.81Hz to 1MHz, exactly as specified in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LTC6992 is specified to maintain a specific accuracy up to a frequency of 1MHz. However, it is very much physically capable of running at a higher frequency, which is actually even mentioned on page 22 in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf) you linked: "When  operating  with  I<sub>SET</sub>  outside  of  the  recommended  1.25μA  to  20μA  range,  the  master  oscillator  operates  outside of the 62.5kHz to 1MHz range in which it is most accurate." It also notes "it is not recommended to operate the master oscillator beyond 2MHz because the accuracy of the DIV pin ADC will suffer."

It's perfectly fine to run this chip at 2MHz (or even a bit above that). If you want it to not exceed 1MHz, you have to make sure that the SET resistor doesn't drop below 50kOhm.

Comment: I struggle to see a direct note about higher frequencies but I'm sure you're right based on the behavior I'm seeing. Thanks for the answer, and any supporting detail you can add would be appreciated. In the meantime, I'm going to redesign R<sub>SET</sub> to be adjustable to a specific low and high bound (using more pots!)

Comment: Thanks for adding those details! I added a direct quote in there for permanent context, and I've confirmed clamping the resistance fixes my circuit up nicely. Thanks!